# Choosing a background image via CSS, what are the differences?

Tags: css

I'm playing around with some CSS and so far all of these seem to do the same:

```
background: url('/images/file.png');
background: image-url('file.png'); /* Doesn't requires as much info about the path. */
background-image: url('/images/file.png');
```

Is there a difference or is it just up to preference?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the second one is invalid CSS.

Comment: @Blender, thanks for pointing that out. Oddly enough it's working in my case. I learned about it from the [Octopress](http://octopress.org/) stylesheets, and that's also where I'm trying it out.

Comment: Could you link me to where you found it? I think the CSS might be pre-processed by Octopress.

Comment: @Blender [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/Y67Hy.png) shows where it occurs. Check out [this repo](https://github.com/rmurphey/blog-octopress/tree/master/sass) for the files (not my repo, but best I could find since these files are usually only found in local repos).
The instance in `_styles.scss` is where I was trying it out.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. SCSS isn't CSS. It's a language that compiles into CSS but is much faster to write.

Comment: @Blender Ah ok, I thought they were just using a different naming convention. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first property declaration is a shorthand:

```
background: #COLOR url('image.png');
```

This is equivalent to this:

```
background-color: #COLOR;
background-image: url('image.png');
```

By omitting the color, you are just specifying the image.

And info on the property from the [CSS2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background-properties):

> The 'background' property is a shorthand property for setting the individual background properties (i.e., 'background-color', 'background-image', 'background-repeat', 'background-attachment' and 'background-position') at the same place in the style sheet.
>   The second one is invalid CSS.

The second one is just invalid CSS. Don't use it.

The third one is preferred, as it doesn't reset the other properties (also from the spec):

> Given a valid declaration, the 'background' property first sets all the individual background properties to their initial values, then assigns explicit values given in the declaration.

Comment: W3 regarding the image URL property in background is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri  Also @Dennis font is another useful (I think) shorthand for CSS. http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-font-shorthand-property-cheat-sheet/ Along with padding and margin, which I use all to frequently. =)